# Nsdateformatter with nsdate for getting exact date in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I want to get the date from xml data ,which is in a string like as given below
"Fri, 06 Feb 2015 11:25:00 -0600"
how can i set the nsdateformatter for this type of date " -0600 is the time zone".
Please help me

Comment: You need to try something ad if you need help then add the code to your question to get more help.

Comment: Maybe you should refer to [the documentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: @Zaph  All your code working for me but i am not getting the timezone as -0600 "GMT" , in your code it show as +0000 , how can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)
Also: [Date Field SymbolTable.](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table), look specifically at "Z".

**Z**   Time Zone: ISO8601 basic hms? / RFC 822 **-0800**

Example:

```
NSString *dateString = @"Fri, 06 Feb 2015 11:25:00 -0600";
NSLog(@"dateString: %@", dateString);
```

Input dateString:

> dateString: Fri, 06 Feb 2015 11:25:00 -0600

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"E, dd MMM yyyy H:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

Output (in timezone GMT):

> date: 2015-02-06 17:25:00 +0000

To create a string from the date in a specific format:

```
NSDateFormatter *displayFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[displayFormatter setDateFormat:@"E, dd MMM yyyy H:mm:ss Z"];
[displayFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CST"]];
NSString *displayString = [displayFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Output (in timezone CST):

> displayString: Fri, 06 Feb 2015 11:25:00 -0600

Comment: All your code working for me but i am not getting the timezone as -0600 "GMT" , in your code it show as  +0000 , how can i do this ?

Comment: Use a Date Formatter set to the output format you want along with a local if necessary with `stringFromDate:` to get a string date formatted as needed. NSLog just uses a default date formatter, it is really just fora debuging.

Comment: I convert date to string using but time is 6 hour increase the time. I  have also set the time zone but i did not get correct time.How  to manage date with set time zone to get correct date with time ?

Comment: The time is kept in GMT by NSDate. Everything else is formatting. So 11:25:00 -0600 is CST which is 6 hours earlier then 17:25:00 +0000 GMT. (Apple uses GMT which is archaic but the same as UTC) Provide an example for both the string you have and the timezone you want the time for and the format you want it in.

Comment: I want to set date "Fri, 06 Feb 2015 11:25:00 -0600" this formate and time zone GMT -6

Comment: Exampie added: Set the timezone on a `NSDateFormatter` and use that to create the `NSString`.